# is there VPN for non browser sources?

Tags: vpn

How to impersonate identity or IP when accessing Internet resources from cmd or Postman? Is it even possible?

I am accessing 'haveIbeenPwned' API from cmd and Postman but getting '403' forbidden error and one of the reason state traffic patterns being similar to other users who may have violated the acceptable use terms.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the first question you should ask yourself is how your queries look, if the service considers them to be on the verge of violating acceptable use terms.

In other words: What are you trying to achieve, and is there a better mechanism for doing that which doesn't, for example, cause unreasonable amounts of traffic?